# Best way to set up subscription billing

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, paypal, e-commerce

I'm on the verge of releasing an app into the Android and WP7 marketplaces (and hopefully iPhone soon after).

The app in the marketplace will be free, but there will be features available for a monthly subscription. Since this won't be running through the marketplace like it would if I was simply charging for the app download, I have to set up this billing myself. Unfortunately, this is something I know very little about. What's the quickest path to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best way to do this is to go with a Subscription Billing System.  We've looked at a few of them and decided between ChargeBee and Zuora. As our model is more complex, we went with Zuora.  For your requirement, ChargeBee should be a good option.  As they are still in the Beta stage, they should be able to help with customization if required.  But I don't think that would be necessary.

http://www.chargebee.com

Comment: Thanks David. I think I wrote this wrong (from my mobile device while falling asleep last night) - I was thinking of how I could CODE this myself, with the paypal API or something. But this looks like an even better option. Thanks!